# Android scrollView not resizing

Tags: android, resize, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

OK so I have a Login Screen that has 2 EditText fields (Username) and (Password).

I've done this

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true" android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:onClick="onLoginClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/more_about"
        android:onClick="onMoreInfo"/>
```

My problem is when i click on username the keyboard hides android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo" button.  I added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" into actity manifest file but nothing is working. Any clue how to do this ??

Comment: You could simply use your ScrollViews scrollTo() method to position it correctly when entering the Edittext.

Comment: @Phil i will try this and see what happends

Comment: This also doesn't work :( it seems the the keyboard is over the complete layout. I just wanted to resize the view if the keyboard is there

Answer (score 0):

I would make LinearLayout's `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and

```
     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnMoreInfo"
            ...
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      />

     <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            ...
            android:layout_above="@id/btnMoreInfo"
      />
```

Comment: also not working don't know if it have to be because of fullscreen enabled